# Sendkeys selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, sendkeys

I am scraping a website using selenium with python. This website has a search engine that allows you to write. When I include the text, before hitting enter, I need to wait some time, otherwise it does the search. I wanted to know if there is a way to include a fluentwait instead of using `time.sleep()`

```
search_text = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#wuSearch')
search_text.click()
search_text.clear()
search_text.send_keys('text')
#time.sleep(2)
search_text.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: you're probably waiting for auto complete options or something similar?

Comment: I'm quite sure `WebDriverWait` can be used here, but we need to see the web page you are working on to see what event / element state can be used to wait for

Comment: The webpage is [this](https://www.wunderground.com/) @Prophet

Comment: @RolandasUlevicius Yes I think so

Comment: Just like @Prophet said, you can use WebDriverWait. Look for autocomplete element locator (it will appear in html, look for it in devtools), and just wait while it shows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different types of waits in selenium. You can find [Selenium waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)
also, you can use [Explicit waits](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/explicit-waits-in-selenium-python/?ref=lbp) or [Implicit waits](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implicit-waits-in-selenium-python/?ref=lbp) based on your code.